# Angular 5, ng build --prod, не работает ngModel, а также ngModelChange

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular4

Здравствуйте, может вопрос и банальный, но я только начал изучать ангуляр, и столкнулся с такой проблемой: `ngModel` и `ngModelChange` замечательно работает, если запускать проект через `ng serve` или собирать через `ng build`, но когда дело доходит до `ng build --prod`, почему-то этот функционал перестает работать.

.ts

```js
export class LoginPopup {
  emailStr = '';
  emailInputChange() {
    console.log(this.emailStr);
  }
}
```

.html

```html
<form>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input
        matInput
        email
        placeholder="Email"
        name="email"
        [(ngModel)]="emailStr"
        (ngModelChange)="emailInputChange()"
      >
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
```

В `app.module.ts` `FormsModule` подключен, не могу понять где я налажал.

P.S. Использую еще Angular Material, может быть это как-то с этим связано?

Comment: Какая-то ошибка возникает во время `ng build --prod`? Как вы потом проверяете сбилденный сайт?

Comment: Никаких ошибок не возникает, сбилденный сайт просто открываю index.html в браузере, или на `nodejs` на локалхосте, там тоже нет никаких ошибок в консоли, но я немного поковырялся и заметил, что тут дело скорее всего не в `ngModel`, сами инпуты как-то неправильно работают, в том числе валидация email средствами `FormControl`, у меня инпуты открываются в модальном окне `MatDialog`, может это как-то влияет... Сейчас пробую сделать без него, может все будет нормально...

Comment: Еще есть вероятность, что когда вы запускаете просто `index.html` ангуляр не может загрузить какие-то ресурсы. Попробуйте на каком-нибудь сервере проверить.

Comment: Запускал на сервере, все тоже самое. Вообщем отказался я от модальных окон, форму авторизации отдельной страницей сделал, теперь все хорошо.

Comment: Наверное, стоит открыть [issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/new).